# Scaling/resolution in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop

i recently got a new laptop and am having issues exporting maps. When i click to export, the GIS screen essentially freezes up, but what actually happens is the box to save as is opening behind the gis screen and i cant see it. I was told it was a resolution/scaling issue however i have tried every possible setting and have had no luck.

Does anyone have any insight as to how to correct this?

Comment: https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-questions/hidden-dialog-box-occurs-while-geoprocessing-model/td-p/656939

Comment: Which of the ArcGIS Desktop applications and it’s version are you using?